Can Archaic Seal apply to items obtained from Fateful Twist?
The description of Archaic Seal says "Your next Well of Charon item with a duration will instead expire after 2 Guardian(s)." When you have this item, the Seal icon will appear below any Well of Charon items it can apply to. However, I noticed it doesn't appear below Fateful Twist which says "Gain a random item offered from the Well of Charon".
If you buy a Fateful Twist from the Well of Charon while Archaic Seal is active and it gives you an item with a duration, will the changed duration from Archaic Seal apply to that new item?


At the time of this answer, an item bought with Fateful Twist while under Archaic Seal's effect won't be affected by the Archaic Seal's effect, but instead will work like a regular item bought in normal circumstances.
